# CSS reset via „all: unset“ breaks inline SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

When using a CSS reset like

```
* {
  all: unset;
}
```

inline SVG graphics are not shown correctly, see https://jsfiddle.net/593qysxp/1/

I have tested this with Safari 11 and Chrome 61.

I tried to solve this with setting the svg element to `display: block` or `all: initial`but this did not help.

Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: If you check what happens via dev tools, you see that it makes the calculated values for svg element properties such as cx, cy, rx, ry, ... either 0 or auto ... _"Does anyone has a solution?"_ - don't use the nuclear option for a "css reset" ...?

Comment: This would be valid solution indeed, but - as long as you only targeting certain browsers and/or in my case an electron app - this is the easiest way to start with a clean slate.

Comment: Why would that be a bug? [SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes) states cx and cy are presentation attributes on circle and ellipse elements, as d is on path.

Comment: You are required to show your code here, not a third party site which can go dead tomorrow and help no one: [mcve]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to leave SVG content completely alone and not reset anything inside them, you could use

```
@namespace svg "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

:not(svg|*) {
  all: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes) now defines a number of attributes as presentation attributes that were true XML attributes in SVG 1.1. Among them are cx, cy, rx, ry for `<ellipse>` elements and the d attribute for `<path>` elements.

That has the consequence that these, when written as attributes on the element, are treated as CSS properties. That is why they are overwritten by `all: unset`. (according to SVG 1.1 rules, see Addendum below.)

That means equally that they can be stated in a `style` attribute, where they would have a higher specicifity than any stylesheet.

As not all browser implement these presentation attributes yet, you would have to state them for now double as attributes and style properties. The result looks weird, if you ask me:

```css
* {
  all: unset;
}

head, link, meta, script, style, title {
  display: none;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.icon {
  width: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg class="icon icon--search" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
       version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <ellipse cx="14.159" cy="5.87" rx="5.89" ry="5.849"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;cx:14.159px;cy:5.87px;rx:5.89px;ry:5.849px"/>
    <path d="M10,10l-9.98,10.02"
        style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;d:path('M10,10l-9.98,10.02')"/>
  </svg>  
</div>
```

The use of the `path()` functional notation is, by the way, still an open [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652822). So this may currently work, but not for long. This whole technique looks like something that I would not advise to use.

**Addendum:** Things get further complicated by a breaking change in the SVG spec I wasn't aware of until I just read up on it. SVG 1.1 has [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#UsingPresentationAttributes) to say about the CSS cascade:

> The presentation attributes thus will participate in the CSS2 cascade as if they were replaced by corresponding CSS style rules placed **at the start** of the author style sheet with a specificity of zero.

SVG 2 instead says [this](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes):

> Presentation attributes contribute to the author level of the cascade, **following all other** author-level style sheets, and have specificity 0.

First or last? So far I have not encountered any browser where presentation attributes supplant author style sheet rules. That includes this example. Following SVG 2 rules, your stylesheet rule should have been replaced by the attributes, but obviously weren't.